# How can I pull multiple private sources into my pipeline agent on Azure?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am currently running into an issue where I am **able** to pull from one private GitHub source in the `checkout` stage but **unable** to pull another private GitHub source from a `script` later in the pipeline due to lack of access rights. Note: Both Repos are a part of the same organization. And I've already connected the Azure App to GitHub with access to all Repos

Within my `checkout` stage I've explicitly set `persistCredentials: true`. This, as I understand it, should allow the following scripts in the pipeline to use the GitHub credentials that were used in the checkout for "Get Sources".

Here is an example of the script that fails:

```
- script: |
git clone --branch=username --single-branch 
https://github.com/username/myRepo.git $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/myRepo
displayName: 'clone myRepo'
```

And the output:

```
Generating script.
[command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/_temp/cb2622cc-28e0-435a-bb98-154bdabf9641.sh
Cloning into '/Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/myRepo'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured
##[error]Bash exited with code '128'
```

Comment: Your example shows you're using HTTPS to clone, but the output error message "Host key verification failed" implies that you're using SSH to clone.  Are you in fact using HTTPS, or are you using SSH?

Comment: I've attempted to clone using both SSH and HTTPS. I must have pulled the wrong log for my example here. I'll update it.

Comment: You're definitely missing credentials ("Device not configured" means you're attempting to read them from the nonexistent terminal), but I don't know how to fix that on Azure.

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming that even though I am explicitly "persisting credentials", it's not actually happening.

Comment: How do you set persistCredentials: true

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT right under `checkout`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=vsts&tabs=schema#checkout

Comment: Any luck getting this working? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Are you using one or multiple `task` or `job` entries? You need to ensure that all the clones are happening on the same node (via correct structuring of the config) as that is where the credentials are actually persisted, ie new node = no persisted data available. Using steps under a single Job is probably the best route. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 2):

I was running in to this as well. I ended up installing a new deploy key with the [InstallSSHKey task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops). The steps are pretty straightforward.

1. On a local machine generate a key with `ssh-keygen -f <key file name>`
2. Upload the private key to a [secure file in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops)
3. Grab github's public rsa key using `ssh-keyscan github.com`
4. Add the following to your `azure-pipelines.yml`

```
steps:
# ...
- task: InstallSSHKey@0
  inputs:
    knownHostsEntry: github.com ssh-rsa ...  # Github's public key from ssh-keyscan
    sshPublicKey: ssh-rsa ... # The public key (.pub) to key you generated
    sshKeySecureFile: my_deploy_key # This is the name you gave the secure file when you uploaded it
- script: |
    git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
# ...
```

5. Add the public key as a deploy key to the repo you need to clone in github.

IIRC, you can only use a deploy key in one repo, so it may be necessary to do this for each repository you need to clone.

PS. I find Azure Pipelines' task documentation a little hard to follow, but most tasks are defined in [this repo](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks). Here is the definition of the [InstallSSHKey task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/InstallSSHKeyV0/task.json) I used.